# Post data from backbone to REST

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

I'm just starting with Backbone.js, and trying to create a simple `Add to wish list` part of my project. Assuming that I have a detail page for each item, and in the page contain `Add to wish list` button.

This is my model :

```
var WishList = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url:'http://blahblah.com/Qts/WL.svc/AddWishlist'
});

var _wishList = new WishList();

//here the sample data that I want to get from my view as : 
_wishList.set({
            "ID" : 0,
            "Name" : "",
            "CustomerID" : 106,
            "Type" : 0,
            "LastUpdated" : "\/Date(1383152400000+0700)\/",
            "WishlistDetail" : [
                {
                    "ID" : 0,
                    "WishListID" : 0,
                    "ItemID" : 22776,
                    "Quantity" : 2,
                    "LastUpdated" : "\/Date(1383152400000+0700)\/"
                }
            ]
        });

_wishList.save();
```

How can I take the `wishlist` object from my `view` to `model` (like sample data above) when clicking on `Add to wish list` button in the item detail page, then post it to REST.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to provide a reference to your wishlist to the view ala:

```
var _wishList = new WishList();
var _wishlistView = new WishlistView({
    model : _wishList
});
```

You should then be able to set the model from the view like so:

```
var WishlistView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el  : "#wishlist-el",
    events : {
        "click"  : "handleClick"
    },
    initialize : function(options){
        //Bind the click handler to this view to retain "this"
        _.bindAll(this, 
            "handleClick"
        );
    },
    handleClick : function(e){
          this.model.set({
              "WishlistDetail" : [
                 {
                     "ItemID" : 47984357,
                     "Quantity" : 50,
                     "LastUpdated" : "\/Date(1383152400000+0700)\/"
                 }
              ]     
              ....
          })
    }
})
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I've been travelling. Anyway, the click button is in the `HomeView`, so I cannot use `model : _wishList`.